# Question about for loop(initialization, condition, updation)

Tags: c++

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char* a = new char[5];

    for (char i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a[i] = 'x';
    }

    for (char i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

How can this code compile without error??
I thought for loop condition should be int i.

Question:

1. I'm confused in this initialization and condition part. Because of type implicit conversion, char i = (char)0 and i is a character maybe?? Then, how can evaluate this condition because char i < int 5?
2. Even though i is a character, can I use this i++?

Comment: ***Even though i is a character, can I use this i++?*** Yes. A char is likely an 8 bit signed or unsigned but could be larger depending in the implementation.

Comment: in C and C++ `char` means integer of at least 8 bits

Comment: *"I thought for loop condition should be int i"*??? The loop condition can be anything that is convertible to `bool`. And in your case `i < 5` is the loop condition, not `char i = 0`. comparison between a smaller type and a larger type is not an issue, since a type conversion is automatically added. Anyways it would be better to use `size_t`, not `int` to avoid unnecessary conversions: `for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Modern hardware platforms have 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit integers. 8-bit integers are `char`s. That's all that a `char` is. It's just a single byte, an 8 bit integer.

You can use `char` anywhere as long as the actual integer values you're using fit within the range of a `char`. Signed 8-bit chars range in values from -128 to 127. Here, the shown code only needs to count from 0 to 5, so a `char` counter will work just fine. The only downside is that the code looks a slightly confusing. And it confused you. But, except for this minor confusion, it works just fine as is.

All operators that work on an `int` will also work on a `char`, including `++` and `--`, as well as `*`, `/`, `%`, `+`, and `-`. The only requirement is that the underlying values fit within `char`'s numerical range.

Answer (score 1):

The type `char` is one byte long, positive and negative values (-128 to 127). It stores a number, exactly as any other variable types. So, you can use all the operators available for primitive types. The difference is when you uses the `printf` function, you have to indicate it as `c` to get its representation of a char, if you use the integer specifiers, like `i` or `d` you'll get the number stored in it. So

1. In your code `char i = 0`, the compiler will initiate the variable with the value zero. Which in the ASCII table is represented as a NULL char.
2. Yes you can use the ++ operator, and any other operators that works with primitive types (also math operators and calculus).

Is more efficient when you uses char type to work with strings, so, the compiler don't need to convert anything.